# QtWebEngine: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on custom Yocto image

Tags: openssl, qt5, chromium, yocto, qtwebengine

I am currently not able to visit any HTTPS-based web site from a QML WebEngineView... I obtain the following error page:

> **This site can't provide a secure connection**
>
> (site-name-here) sent an invalid response
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

while on console I have the following error:

> ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1101)] handshake failed; returned -1,
>   SSL error code 1, net_error -107

I am working on a custom Yocto (rocko) image, including `qt5` and `ca-certificates` recipes.

Is there something to configure on the image for allowing QtWebEngine (Chromium) to access the installed certificates?

How can I check the list of installed certificates available for QtWebEngine (Chromium)?

Since the error message is quite generic, how can I increase (if possible) the verbosity of the error?

Is there something else I need to know about this kind of stuff?

---

*** UPDATE ***

I tried to cURL and WGET the same web server from the same device and everything was fine with that... so I think that the problem is strictly related to QtWebEngine (and/or Chromium).

cURL output:

```
root@imx6dl:~# curl -v https://www.youtube.com -o output.html
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.youtube.com/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 216.58.205.110...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.youtube.com (216.58.205.110) port 443 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/c
erts/ca-certificates.crt
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: *.google.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: EC/ECDSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google LLC,CN=*.google.com
*        start date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 10:34:31 GMT
*        expire date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 09:27:00 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=Google Trust Services,CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.youtube.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
< P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=it for more info."
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Wed, 16 May 2018 06:04:40 GMT
< Server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
< Set-Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=ZnHYI40gIu0; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Mon, 12-Nov-2018 06:04:40 GMT; ht
tponly
< Set-Cookie: YSC=WB62WY8_qvg; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; httponly
< Set-Cookie: PREF=f1=50000000; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Mon, 14-Jan-2019 17:57:40 GMT
< Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":4
43"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{ [376 bytes data]
100  472k    0  472k    0     0   380k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  380k
* Connection #0 to host www.youtube.com left intact
root@imx6dl:~#
```

WGET output:

```
root@imx6dl:~# wget -v https://www.youtube.com
--2018-05-16 06:26:57--  https://www.youtube.com/
Resolving www.youtube.com... 216.58.205.78, 216.58.205.110, 216.58.205.142, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com|216.58.205.78|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html.3'

index.html.3                   [  <=>     ] 453.84K   702KB/s    in 0.6s

2018-05-16 06:26:58 (702 KB/s) - 'index.html.3' saved [464732]

root@imx6dl:~#
```